# Запуск в отдельном процессе

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Что означает строка?

```
make mock-server 2>&1 > /dev/null &
```

По действию это работает как запуск в отдельном процессе. Но как это осуществляется, мне не ясно.

Comment: shell делает fork и не дожидаясь завершения процесса переходит к чтению новой команды.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> /dev/null
```

Перенаправляет stdout в /dev/null

```
2>&1
```

Перенаправляет stderr(fd=2) в stdout(fd=1), т.е. теперь тоже в /dev/null

```
& на конце
```

Убирает задачу в "фоновый режим"

В итоге задача выполняется в фоне, её можно увидеть в списке фоновых задач:

```
jobs
```

Или поднять на первый план `fg`/`fg %1`(1 - номер задачи), только толку в этом мало, любой вывод уже заглушен)

---

Пример:

```
$ yes > /dev/null &
[1] 1787331
$ jobs
[1]+  Запущен          yes > /dev/null &
$ fg
yes > /dev/null
^C
$
```